# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null

Tags: javascript, html, null, row

I am trying to do an xml data parsing to html dynamic table.
I have written the following code,ı am new in javascript.
but when ı am debugging it says that error in debug:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null.
can you help me ? 
code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open("GET", "today.xml", false); 
req.send(null);

var xmlDoc = req.responseXML;       

var nsResolver = xmlDoc.createNSResolver( xmlDoc.ownerDocument == null ? xmlDoc.documentElement : xmlDoc.ownerDocument.documentElement);

var iterator = xmlDoc.evaluate('/Tarih_Date/Currency', xmlDoc, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
var result = iterator.iterateNext();
var x = result.textContent;
var table = document.getElementById("xmlTable")
while (null != result.textContent)
{

    var row = table.insertRow(0);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

    cell1.innerHTML = result.childNodes[3].textContent;
    cell2.innerHTML = result.childNodes[5].textContent;
    cell3.innerHTML = result.childNodes[7].textContent;
    cell4.innerHTML = result.childNodes[9].textContent;

    result=iterator.iterateNext();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


<table id="xmlTable">

</table>


</body>
</html>
```

okey all the code is that.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the var table? because the table doesn't seem to have a rows array. I think you may have configured it wrong.

Comment: okey ı added it like this

Comment: document.getElementById("xmlTable"); returns an html object, not a javascript object, so it doesn't have a rows array.table.insertRow(0); won't work because of that. You think you're editing the XML but that's not possible anymore. Do you want to recreate your table?

Comment: yeap ı want to create my table how ı can fix it ? actually ı dont want to edit xml,ı want to take data in the xml and give it to that with html table to screen using javascript.

Comment: And what's in your result.textContent? could you provide some more code? then I might be able to create a JSfiddle. Thanks!

Comment: in ı am debugging giving that error to me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null

Comment: And what is in today.xml?

Comment: its a xml file. my problem is about to cannot read property rows of null. not to today Xml

Comment: okey ı solved this problem. need the <body> and table tags top of the <script> tag problem solved :) thanks :)